# Performance issue with MDX Calculation in easyBI

Tags: jira, mdx, olap

In easyBI (a BI tool inside JIRA that uses MDX to create custom calculations for reports) I used this below custom calculation to retrieve the latest execution from the Xray test plans (a test management tool inside JIRA). It is working well but not with the test plans having large tests executions inside, with this type of test plans the report will enter an infinite loop and usually will send a time out error at the end:

```
-- annotations. Group=Xray User defined
CASE WHEN
  [Xray Test Run Status].CurrentMember.Level.Name = "Status"
THEN --count tests by last execution status
  Cache(NonZero(Count(
    Filter(
      --iterate throug all Tests
      Descendants([Xray Test].CurrentMember, [Xray Test].[Test]),
      [Measures].[Xray Tests with executions] > 0 AND
      Order(
        --iterate through execution statuses for a selected Test
        Filter([Xray Test Run Status].[Status].Members,
          [Measures].[Xray Tests with executions] > 0),
          
        --order statuses by execution date descending
        DateParse(
          Generate(
            Tail(
              --iterate through all dates when a Test was executed
              Filter([Time].[Day].Members,
                [Measures].[Xray Tests with executions] > 0
              )).Item(0),
            Format([Time].CurrentHierarchyMember.StartDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
            ",")),
        BDESC
        --name of the last execution matches status in columns
      ).item(0) IS [Xray Test Run Status].CurrentMember)
  )))  
ELSE --total count of tests with executions
  ([Measures].[Xray Tests with executions],
  [Xray Test Run Status].DefaultMember)
END
```

source of MDX: easyBI community

[image]

Is there any optimisation possible in the MDX to make the easyBI reports faster?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is resolved, it is not due to the MDX calculation mentioned above but instead it is because of another selected dimension for status execution, once that dimension is removed that would no longer be any performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem back to “unresolved”, unfortunately, I noticed an issue with the statics in the new reports when I used the “TestRunStatus” dimension instead of the “Xray Test Run Status” dimension. The “TestRunStatus” doesn’t give the last run only instead it gives the cumulative execution of a test. Can I filter the MDX with status execution instead?